# Unable to load script partial into an html header

Tags: twig

I'm currently working on integrating google analytics into a project. However, when I try to load the partial with the `<script>` code the partial is not loaded into the HTML template.

base.twig

```
  ##
  {{ function('wp_head') }}
  {% block head_extras %}
    {% include 'partials/scripts-google-analytics.twig' %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
```

If I open the developer tools, the page loads but the code within the `script` is not added.

here is the script for  partials/scripts-google-analytics.twig

```
{% if function('getenv', 'YOUR_API_KEY') != '' %}
  <script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ function('getenv', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS') }}'></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', "{{ function('getenv', 'YOUR_API_KEY') }}");
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

How can I add a partial to the `head` tag?

Comment: What do `{{ function('getenv', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS') }}` and `{{ function('getenv', 'YOUR_API_KEY') }}` resolve to?

Comment: only for debugging purpose try to add an else statement to the `if function`

Comment: @Matteo I did and I `console.log(error)` it did show the error.

Comment: @vinoaj I'm following this documentation https://github.com/CityOfNewYork/nyco-wp-config

Comment: `getenv` get the environment variable http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is what value is returned by `function('getenv', 'YOUR_API_KEY')` ?

Comment: @vinoaj the value return is from the development variable and is an api key. `development: 'XYPXXXXXXXXX'` Thats what it looks like.

Comment: OK, in that case it should not be there in the `gtag('config', "{{ function('getenv', 'YOUR_API_KEY') }}");` line.